# >Date() Query Criteria not returning accurate results

Tags: date, ms-access

Today's date is 6/9/2015... I want my query to show me everything after todays date (I use query criteria >Date())... I have two dates that should show: 6/18/2015 and 7/2/2015. The only date that the query returns is 7/2/2015. Any ideas as to why?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the dates are in a string format, try to convert them to a date format when making the compare.